# Javascript Movie Classification program

Tags: javascript

Helo guys, i'm tryng to create a movie classification program in javascript  and i can't seam to get it right . My code is as follows.?

function canIWatch(age){

```
if ( age <= 6 ){
                document.write("You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.")
              }



else if( age >= 6 || age <= 17 ){
                document.write("You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.")
              }



else if( age >= 17 || age <= 25 ){
                document.write("You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.")
              }


else if ( age > 25 ){
                document.write("Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!")
              }



else {
                document.write("Invalid age.")
              }
```

}

Comment: You haven't told what the problem is, but I'm guessing it's because you have `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to group age into groups, You'll have to use logical AND `&&` instead of OR `||` because with OR if a single condition is met the corresponding code is executed.

```
if (age <= 6) {
  document.write("You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.")
} else if (age >= 6 && age <= 17) {
  document.write("You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.")
} else if (age >= 17 && age <= 25) {
  document.write("You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.")
} else if (age > 25) {
  document.write("Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!")
} else {
  document.write("Invalid age.")
}
```